# highlight like whatsapp message selection for deletion in iOS using objective-C

Tags: ios, uitableview, whatsapp

How to highlight similar to selection of whatsapp messages for deletion using objective-c in table view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you cell add another view on top of all controls in uitableviewcell and also keep an array of same size as the chat array is having. now all cells for whome you want it to be highlighted, store 1 in that array and for others store 0. and in cellForRowAtIndexpath delegate method, check that the value in array is 0 or 1, if it is 1 then change the color of that view as you like or otherwise keep its color clearColor.